# PHP 5.3 and anonymous function default values?

Tags: php, function, anonymous

In php 5.3, when you create an anonymous function, can you set the default values?

Like in a normal functon you do

> function tim($a=123){
>
> }

where 123 is the default value for $a. What abut in anonymous functions?

**UPDATE**

I'm having trouble with it in this context:

```
//$data is an object;
$data->title = 'test';
add_filter('title',function($current, $new = $data->title ){ return $new; });
```

produces "unexpected T_VARIABLE"

works fine without the `$data->title` bit, but I really want to pass this in...

```
add_filter('title',function($current, $new = 'some-title' ){ return $new; });
```

I'm adding a filter in Wordpress. Works fine if I explicitly set it, but I want to pull it from another variable. Is that possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ php -r '$foo = function($a = 123){echo $a, PHP_EOL;};$foo(1);$foo();'
1
123
```

So that's a yes

### Update

You can only assign simple values to argument defaults. From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

Try passing the external variable via the `use` keyword

```
add_filter('title', function($current, $new = null) use ($data) {
    if (null === $new) {
        $new = $data->title;
    }
    return $new;
});
```

Comment: i'm having trouble with this for some reason. let me see if I can get it.

Comment: perfect! didn't know that "use" existed! :)

Comment: You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set the default values like that

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using an anonymous function in PHP from the PHP website.

```
<?php
echo preg_replace_callback(
  '~-([a-z])~',
  function ($match) {
    return strtoupper($match[1]);
  },
  'hello-world'
);
```

See the `function ($match) {` part? You can define the in there like any other function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my tiny library [ValueResolver](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) in this case, for example:

```
add_filter('title', function($current, $new = null) use ($data) {
    return ValueResolver::resolve($new, $data->title);
});
```

and don't forget to use namespace `use LapaLabs\ValueResolver\Resolver\ValueResolver;`

There are also ability to typecasting, for example if your variable's value should be `integer`, so use this:

```
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('6 apples', 1); // returns 6
$id = ValueResolver::toInteger('There are no apples', 1); // returns 1 (used default value)
```

Check the [docs](https://github.com/LapaLabs/ValueResolver) for more examples